# Can't delete an element from my store and upgrade my component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components

Here is my component i just list some elements

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { delFruit} from "../../js/actions/index";

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
    console.log(dispatch);
    return {
        delFruit: fruits => dispatch(delFruit(fruits))
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {fruits: state.fruits};
};



class ConnectedList extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(el)
    {
        this.props.delFruit(el)
    }

    render()
    {
        // const fruits = this.state.fruits

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="title">Liste des courses</div>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {
                        this.props.fruits.map((el, key) => (
                            <li key={key}>
                                {el.name} <i>( {el.price} € )</i> <i className="delete"  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, key)}></i>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );

    }
}


const List = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedList);

export default List;
```

When i want to delete an element i use this script

```
import {ADD_FRUIT, DELETE_FRUIT, DOUBLE_FRUIT} from "../constants/action-types";
import fruits from "../../data/fruits";
const initialState = {
    fruits: fruits['elements'],
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action)
{
    if (action.type === ADD_FRUIT) {
        return Object.assign({}, {}, {
            fruits: state.fruits.concat(action.payload)
        });
    }
    if (action.type === DELETE_FRUIT) {
        delete state.fruits[action.payload];

        return Object.assign({}, {}, {
            fruits:state.fruits
        });

    }
    if (action.type === DOUBLE_FRUIT) {
    }
    return state;
}

export default rootReducer;
```

When i inspect the state of my component , the element is properly deleted (in example #2)

[image]

But my component does not remove it from the list

The only way i manage to make it work is doing this

```
return Object.assign({}, {}, {
            fruits:state.fruits.concat()
        });
```

instead of

```
return Object.assign({}, {}, {
            fruits:state.fruits
        });
```

- why my component is not updated without concat()
- How is the good way of doing it
- why my array keep a null value after deleting

Answer (score 1):

You can delete that using spread operator. Here's a basic snippet showing how to do that.

```js
const state = {
  fruits: [1,2,3]
}

const action = {
  index: 1
}

const newState = [
              ...state.fruits.slice(0, action.index),
              ...state.fruits.slice(action.index + 1)
            ];

console.log(newState);
```

So you can modify your code to:

```
if (action.type === DELETE_FRUIT) {
    return {
        ...state,
        fruits: [
              ...state.fruits.slice(0, action.payload),
              ...state.fruits.slice(action.payload + 1)
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! it worked  like a charm, can you explain me why my code gave me that result ?